# Python print with string invalid syntax

Tags: python

I have a rock, paper, scissors code I've been working on lately (yes, I am a total noob at coding), and I get an Invalid Syntax error with this specific line:

```
print('The magical 8ball reads "Your fortune will come soon." It then turns over. It now reads "YOU'RE DEAD." You get suffocated by the paper.')
```

I don't know what's wrong and I haven't been able to find an answer. Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: The syntax highlighting is a big hint.

Comment: Take a look at your editors syntax highlighting. Or even here on SO in your question. Doesn't it seem off?

Comment: Thanks, I don't have syntax highlighting on my editor, so little things like this don't get noticed. But thanks for the help :)

Comment: Consider getting such an editor. It will help a lot.

Comment: Please mark the answer that fixed you issue instead of adding `[ANSWERED]`

Comment: Geez, chill, I'm not only a n00b at coding but also new here, I can't know EVERY rule here -_-

Comment: @kompis231 Don't change it back then, I just told you and said please but you roll it back.

Comment: @EpicKip i did it so people won't come here to answer.

Comment: @kompis231 People can see if you've accepted an answer (also from search) - Stop editing it, it is against the rules (To edit in noise, this is not a forum) and I've told you to not do it already.

Comment: Geez, dude, chillax. Sorry then..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `single quote` in the sentence causing the quote doesn't close properly.

**Try this:**

```
print('The magical 8ball reads "Your fortune will come soon." It then turns over. It now reads "YOU\'RE DEAD." You get suffocated by the paper.')
```

Answer (score 0):

Using 3 single or double quotes to enclose the print statement.

print('''The magical 8ball reads "Your fortune will come soon." It then turns over. It now reads "YOU'RE DEAD." You get suffocated by the paper.''') 
or 
print("""The magical 8ball reads "Your fortune will come soon." It then turns over. It now reads "YOU'RE DEAD." You get suffocated by the paper.""")

Answer (score 0):

I think You should try escape characters.

Let's try this:- print("The magical 8ball reads \"Your fortune will come soon.\" It then turns over. It now reads. \"YOU'RE DEAD.\" You get suffocated by the paper.")

Answer (score 0):

If you try to debug on ur own you will see.. that a string is written in quotes.
 ' xyz ' or "xyz". You can not mix quotes likr. 
'xy'z'. This is invalid as your string end at y only. 
To add apostrophe s you need to use backslash syntax and double quotes.

Something like - print('xy/'z')

/' is what you are looking for.